# Escape JavaScript event scope

Tags: javascript, html, scope, html5-canvas, dom-events

I'm  new to the way JavaScript scopes, so this is my problem:

```
"use strict";

function Explorer(xPos, yPos) {

    // Inheritance
    GraphicsEntity.call(this, {
        x: xPos,
        y: yPos,
        width: 32,
        height: 32
    });

    // Local fields
    var _texture = new Image();

    // Contruct
    _texture.addEventListener("load", function() {

        this.graphics.drawImage(_texture, 0, 0);

    }, false);

    _texture.src = "explorer.png";

}
```

This will throw the exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'drawImage' of undefined

I know that this is due to the way JavaScript scopes, since 'this' now refers to the '_texture' field.
As you can see Explorer (some kind of player-like object) inherits from GraphicsObject that in turn has a property graphics (the context of a canvas element).

I've found a way to fix this problem but in my opinion it's a bit of a dirty one:

```
"use strict";

function Explorer(xPos, yPos) {

    // Inheritance
    GraphicsEntity.call(this, {
        x: xPos,
        y: yPos,
        width: 32,
        height: 32
    });

    // Local fields
    var _texture = new Image();
    var _graphics = this.graphics;

    // Contruct
    _texture.addEventListener("load", function() {

        _graphics.drawImage(_texture, 0, 0);

    }, false);

    _texture.src = "explorer.png";

}
```

So all works as expected now, the image is neatly drawn onto the canvas element.
The only problem is that I now have another reference to 'graphics' I don't really want.

So my question is:
Is there any way of making 'this' refer to the Explorer object, or forcing the scope to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is always local to the function, it's evaluated every time a function is called depending on how the function is called. In this case the browser calls the function with `this` set to the image object that `_texture` points to.

Since normal variables are looked up from outer scope, you can simply save the old `this` to some variable:

```
function Explorer(xPos, yPos) {
    var self = this;

    // Inheritance
    GraphicsEntity.call(this, {
        x: xPos,
        y: yPos,
        width: 32,
        height: 32
    });

    // Local fields
    var _texture = new Image();
    // Contruct

    _texture.addEventListener("load", function () {
        self.graphics.drawImage(_texture, 0, 0);
    }, false);

    _texture.src = "explorer.png";
}
```

Comment: So essentially the same way as I fixed it, but using a reference to the entire Object itself? Hmmm... this could work.

Comment: @JonKoops it's better to just use the whole object, it's only a reference so it doesn't take less or more memory (there is still just one representation of the object in memory, even if multiple things point to it). that way you don't need to rewrite when you need something else than `explorer.graphics` in the callback.

Comment: @Esailija Okay, I was just worried about messing up the memory big time. I'll use this approach, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the function `GraphicsEntity`, but I'm pretty sure the problem is this:

```
GraphicsEntity.call(this, {
```

In your function `Explorer`, `this` will be the global object (well, unless `Explorer` was also called with `call`), which is what the call to `call` is setting `this` to in `GraphicsEntity`.  That's likely why you're getting that exception.

Also, is `GraphicsEntity` an *object*, or a *function*?  I ask because `call` is expecting a **function**.  `call` calls the given *function*, setting the first parameter to the `this` value, with subsequent arguments being passed as that function's arguments.

**EDIT**

As Esailija already said, the `this` value is different in your load event callback from what it is in the beginning of your function.  Save the value of `this` to a local variable in the beginning of your function, and use *that* in your callback.

Comment: `Explorer` is used like a normal object, and that seems to work fine. The problem is the scope in the Image.load event.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a wrapper function that will create the context you need and capture your state.

As in:

```
function draw(me) {
    me.graphics.drawImage(_texture, 0, 0);
}

function wrapper(me) {
    return function () { draw(me) };
}

...
_texture.addEventListener('load', wrapper(this));
...
```

Is it less verbose than your solution? It's debatable but you can make it generic enough that it can be reused in other contexts.

Comment: This seems to work, so it preserves the context in a field and returns it so it can be used later. Smart :)

How would I go about making this 'generic enough'?

Nice solution, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Through prototypical inheritance you could make all your interested objects have the `wrapper()` defined. You can also add a second argument as the function itself (separating the wrapper method from the specific method implementation, like so `wrapper(me, f) { return function () { f(me); }; }`). It's debatable whether this is better than using the `self` approach, since it's clearly slower but it is also much more flexible (you might have additional setup in your wrapper method that you might want to share).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, perhaps I will use this method in the future :)

Comment: @JonKoops Sure. The best solution is always the one that best fits your particular use case. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use bind to bind the context to the function scope

"use strict";

function Explorer(xPos, yPos) {

```
// Inheritance
GraphicsEntity.call(this, {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos,
    width: 32,
    height: 32
});

// Local fields
var _texture = new Image();

// Contruct
_texture.addEventListener("load", function() {

    this.graphics.drawImage(_texture, 0, 0);

}.bind(this), false);

_texture.src = "explorer.png";
```

}